# How can I get back into Air Mech?

Tags: airmech

With the latest changes, they removed all my creeps. Now I have the problem, that I have only like 100 Karma left and all my creeps are gone. I cannot buy any and I cannot win matches against the AI. I do not want to bother any team with my failure, so how I can back into the game without spending money and rewarding the devs for making the game pay to win?

Comment: What, they removed creeps?  Why?

Comment: @GnomeSlice Was part of a patch

Answer (score 1):

Finish the tutorial and do as much achievements as you can to get some money to start you off, then choose a specific load out you want to keep, then play matches until you get enough money to buy back what you are missing. Carbon removed most of the startup units because people were having it too easy, they also took back the Airmechs that were on permanent trial for everybody.

Comment: Game popularity: Before patch: %100, after patch: %0.